# Does "whenever convenient" sound natural or not?

Tags: sentence-construction, clauses

Does **whenever convenient** sound natural to you in the following sentence?

> Please call my secretary to arrange a meeting this afternoon, or **whenever convenient to you**.

Does the sentence sound natural to you?

Comment: Does it to you? How/Why?

Comment: This question is phrased like proofreading, so it's understandable that it has a couple close votes.  But it does, in fact, ask about something specific―it's easy to miss since it's only in the question title, not the question body.  It asks about *whenever convenient*.

Comment: @snailboat But the answer to the questions  (if it sounds natural) can only be yes or no. The reason for concern is not stated. I would still call this proofreading.

Comment: @user3169 People who come here are learners of the language. When you are not proficient in a language 1) you have difficulties apprehending what it is you do not fully understand, 2) even more difficulties expressing what your concern is. Those of us who have a greater command of English can help by trying to read behind the words, rephrasing whatever isn't right in the question and ask OPs questions to help them grasp whatever concern they have with a particular structure or grammar point. I read this question as "How can we understand *whenever convenient* and when can we use it?"

Answer (score 4):

The `to` is your main problem.  Something isn't convenient *to* you, it's convenient *for* you.  Compare:

- "I would come to your party, but it isn't convenient **to** me."
- "I would come to your party, but it isn't convenient **for** me."

So `"whenever it is convenient for you"` would be the textbook answer.

Still, it's understandable contracted as `"whenever convenient for you."`  It would even be understood if it was contracted to *"Please call my secretary to arrange a meeting this afternoon, or whenever convenient."*